# Compare timestamps

Tags: javascript, jquery

Would this code work if both the timestamps are in mysql 2013-03-21 18:16:50 format?

```
$.get('current.php', { lastTime: time, current: true, Cla: Class }, function(html) {
                var Date1 = Date.parse($(html).find("#timestamp").val());
                var Date2 = Date.parse($("#timestamp").val());
                if (Date.parse(Date1) < Date.parse(Date2)) {$(html).find("#timestamp").remove();}else {$("#timestamp").remove();}
}
```

Comment: Would it work?...  Did you try it???

Comment: Just did, it doesn't work, I would much appreciate a fix.

Comment: You know that `val()` is only to be used on `<input>` elements?

Comment: both the timestamps are invisible input elements

Comment: @user2191209, what exactly do you want to do with the html that is being returned from the request? Removing something from that fragment won't affect the DOM unless you're going to attach the html to another element that's already in the document. Did you mean to just replace the current timestamp with whichever time is latest?

Comment: I am going to attach that to another element but if the timestamp is newer than the current one I want to attach it without the timestamp.

Comment: @user2191209, can you also attach an example sample server response (i.e., what you see from `console.log(html)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `Date.parse` twice on the values, and `Date.parse` does not accept the milliseconds number returned by the previous invocation as a valid date.

```
if (Date1 < Date2)
```

is enough to compare them. Notice that if either of them could not be parsed, you will be comparing to `NaN`.

Comment: I cannot seem to be able to remove the element from html now, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: That's a different issue, and because `html` is only a string that is parsed each time when you call `$(html)` on it. `remove()` will not alter the HTML string though.

Comment: And how can I remove an element from that string?

Comment: @user2191209: Don't. Create a DOM from the string (something like `var $html = jQuery(html);`) once and operate on/with that only.

Comment: $html.find("#timestampOld2").val() returns NaN even though I know it exists in there.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like this:

```
$.get('current.php', { lastTime: time, current: true, Cla: Class }, function(html) {
  var $dateInput1 = $(html).find('#timestamp'),
      $dateInput2 = $("#timestamp");
  if ($dateInput1.val() < $dateInput1.val()) {
    $dateInput1.remove();
  } else {
    $dateInput2.remove();
  }
  // ... add $html somewhere to the DOM ...
});
```

Since your dates are already in a format that is comparable lexically, it doesn't require using `Date.parse()` at all. Also, you'd only be creating one jQuery object per element, so it's more efficient in that way, too.

Answer (score 1):

Date.parse return time in milliseconds which you can use it for comparison.

```
if (Date1 < Date2) {
          $(html).find("#timestamp").remove();
   }else {
       $("#timestamp").remove();
  }
```

Comment: Neither `Date1` nor `Date2` are `Date` instances here, this code will even throw an exception.